# Configure Kibana Monitoring with Docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

I am using Kibana and ElasticSearch docker images and I would like to get some performance metrics, however, Monitoring tab is not visible in Kibana. According to the documentation, I have added environment variable Xpack_monitoring_enabled to Kibana image in docker-compose.yml, but nothing changes and I still do not see Monitoring tab.

How can I configure Xpack for monitoring in my docker-compose.yml?

Here is docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  kafka:
      image: spotify/kafka
      ports:
        - "9092:9092"
      environment:
      - ADVERTISED_HOST=localhost
  elasticsearch:
      image: elasticsearch:latest
      ports:
        - "9200:9200"
        - "9300:9300"
      networks:
        - docker_elk
      environment:
        - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
      volumes:
         - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  kibana:
      image: kibana:latest
      ports:
        - "5601:5601"
      networks:
        - docker_elk
      environment:
        - XPACK_MONITORING_ENABLED=true
volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local

networks:
  docker_elk:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker image you are using for both elasticsearch and kibana are old images, which are deprecated (see [https://hub.docker.com/*/kibana/*](https://hub.docker.com/_/kibana/) and [https://hub.docker.com//elasticsearch/](https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/))

You should use images coming from the offical elasticsearch registry, such as:

- docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch
- docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana

More details on those images and how to configure them (including xpack with the monitoring plugin you need) here:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/docker.html